# Importing Bootstrap to Vue 3 causes net::ERR_ABORTED 504 (Gateway Timeout)

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-5, vite

I am following [the instructions here](https://larainfo.com/blogs/how-to-install-bootstrap-5-in-vue-3) but when I add the line `import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"` to the `main.js` file I get the error on the network `net::ERR_ABORTED 504 (Gateway Timeout)` and a blank white screen.  Nothing renders. When I comment out that import `bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js` the app works as expected.

This is what I have in the `main.js` file:

````
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue';

import './assets/main.css';


createApp(App).mount('#app');

import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"```



This is my package.json details.


```  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
    "vue": "^3.2.44"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.1.2",
    "vite": "^3.1.8"
  }
````

Any ideas?

Comment: It's unknown at which request the error happens. Currently only you can know that. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi Estus, thanks for response.  It's the request for `bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js`that causes the error.   If I comment out that import statement the error goes away.  So I believe somehow that the `npm install bootstrap` might not have worked entirely correctly

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it but don't know exactly why.  I removed the node_modules `rm -rf node_moduels` and then installed again `npm install` and then ran `npm run dev` and all the issues had ironed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to restart the server thats it