# ERR_ABORTED 504 (Gateway Timeout) while importing a Stencil library in Vite in a Vue application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite, stenciljs, http-status-code-504

I am trying to import a custom web component from a web component library built with StencilJS in my Vue application created with Vite (version 4.0.4). This is the code in my main.js file:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import { defineCustomElements } from '@arnab7/cheesejs/loader';

createApp(App).mount('#app');

defineCustomElements(window);
```

In my App.vue, this is what is ausing the issue:

```
<template>
  <div id="body">
    <checker-board></checker-board>
  </div>
</template>
```

The `<checker-board></checker-board>` is causing the error. The full error text is:

"GET http://localhost:5174/node_modules/.vite/deps/checker-board.entry.js?import net::ERR_ABORTED 504 (Gateway Timeout)
TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:5174/node_modules/.vite/deps/checker-board.entry.js?import undefined
index-e0c21bd2.js:917 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isProxied') at initializeComponent (index-e0c21bd2.js:917:23)"

Removing the web component removes all errors. This is the link to the library (which I created) I am trying to import from: https://github.com/arnab4477/CheeseJS I have followed all the instrutions from Stencil docs while building it and do not see any issue with the library itself. I have seen some similar issues with other libraries as well. However, this library is lazy loaded (Stencil lazy loads all the components) which might be causing the issue with Vite.

I have looked at many similar issues and tried multiple solutions with no success

There are some similar issues on Github where Vite throws this error for other dependencies as well. I followed the suggested solutions but none of them worked. I tried

1. restarting the server
2. deleting and re-installing node_modules
3. deleting the .vite folder from the node_modules, but this would reappear anyway after a restart
4. running this command which I found on github that solved someone's issue: node ./node_modules/esbuild/install.js

I have also seen this very similar question: [Importing Bootstrap to Vue 3 causes net::ERR_ABORTED 504 (Gateway Timeout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74382984/importing-bootstrap-to-vue-3-causes-neterr-aborted-504-gateway-timeout) where restarting and re-installing node_modules fixed the issues. I have tried the solutions but it does not work for me.

I don't know what else to do. Someone please help me.

Edit:

Just to make sure that the problem was on Vite's end and not the library's end, I quickly created a Create React App and tested it there. It works perfectly. So at least I have a solution, but unfortunately it seems like I have to use CRA now which I really didn't want to touch ever again. Anyone have any solution for Vite please?

Comment: do you found a solution for that? I have the same problem

Comment: I found two related issues in the vite repo: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/8146 and https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/8749

Comment: Out of curiousity, why did you not want to work with CRA again?

Answer (score 3):

Here are two related issues/discussions on vite's github repo:

1. [Intermittent HTTP 504 Gateway timeouts fixed by restarts](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/8146)
2. [Error: spawn C:..\node_modules\esbuild\esbuild.exe ENOENT](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1361)

In the latter issue github user [allowing](https://github.com/allowing) commented a solution ([link](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1361#issuecomment-754442599)):

> Run `node ./node_modules/esbuild/install.js`

and github user [evanw](https://github.com/evanw) added ([link](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1361#issuecomment-773720137)):

> It turns out npm v7 has a bug that corrupts package-lock.json files: [npm/cli#2606](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2606). When this happens, packages like esbuild with post install scripts can break. You may be experiencing this bug. A workaround is to delete and recreate your package-lock.json file.

This solved it for me (and others).